# Mod rewrite issue in firefox

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mozilla

I created a .htaccess file that does two things: redirects http to https and also www. to non-www. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.profstream.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://profstream.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works fine in Chrome, Safari, and Opera but for some reason when I type profstream.com/sandbox/login.php for example in Firefox it redirects to https://profstream.com/https://www.profstream.com/sandbox/login.php. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing [L] and also [QSA], try this:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

`L` is to leave, otherwise you will use the rules after this.
`QSA` is to add the query string of the URL.

The second part should be this I think:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.profstream.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://profstream.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Don't know about the `RewriteBase /`, is that needed?

And if you want both to happen, perhaps you should reverse the order

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.profstream.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://profstream.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hmm... Still does that same thing in Firefox... Like I said, it's weird that it works fine in all other browsers minus firefox. Thank you for the detailed answer though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you really sure you are using my suggestion exactly as I wrote them? When you use the rules in your question it's logical that you are getting the result with "combined" URLs. And **don't** use `RewriteBase`. And you tried both suggestions? (using the rules in reverse order).

Comment: Thank you! Turns out your code worked great. Just needed to clear the history.